# How to find an entity dynamically in the context 

Tags: entity-framework

i was wondering if there is any way to find an entity by dynamic string as the entity name .something like the fallowing :

```
MyDataContext ctx=new myDataContext();
ctx.Entities("Customers").First(c => c.Id = 2 ).Name="Alice Brown";
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Even if, you would lose the possibility to write strongly typed lambda expressions like in your example. If you know what `c` is, you know what your entity set's generic type is. Why creating the set then via a string?

Comment: @Slauma:I have multiple table of same type which each one will create for a single year and i have to dynamically call the table based on current year so the table name is TblName+CurrentYear and i didnt design the db it uses by other systems too. thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way but not with strongly typed LINQ. You must use [Entity SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387118.aspx).